# Activate python 3 environemnt in Anaconda with batch-file

Tags: cmd, anaconda

Recently installed Anaconda (1.9) for my python project on win7

After installation, I built a python 3 support environment with instruction in [this page](http://continuum.io/blog/anaconda-python-3). My next task is to activate my python environment automatically with built-in batch file.

I used the command in [Anaconda Command Prompt] shortcut I found in my start menu. It runs a batch-file called [**anaconda.bat**]

After observing the batch file I realized it seems to be capable of taking an input argument that is supposed to be the environment I would like to activate. So I copied the shortcut and modified it as

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "C:\Anaconda\Scripts\anaconda.bat py3k"
```

Then I double clicked on the new shortcut, it opened a new command window but...the designated environment did not activate!

```
@echo off

rem +===========================================================================
rem | Initialisation
rem +===========================================================================
verify bogus-argument 2>nul
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo error: unable to enable command extensions
    goto :eof
)

for %%i in ("%~dp0..\envs") do (
    set ANACONDA_ENVS=%%~fi
)

if not "%1" == "" (
    if not exist "%ANACONDA_ENVS%\%1\python.exe" (
        echo No environment named "%1" exists in %ANACONDA_ENVS%
        goto :eof
    )
    set ANACONDA_ENV_NAME=%1
    set ANACONDA=%ANACONDA_ENVS%\%1
    title Anaconda (%ANACONDA_ENV_NAME%^)
) else (
    set ANACONDA_ENV_NAME=
    for %%i in ("%~dp0..") do (
        set ANACONDA=%%~fi
    )
    title Anaconda
)

set ANACONDA_SCRIPTS=%ANACONDA%\Scripts

for %%i in ("python.exe") do (
    for %%j in ("%ANACONDA%\python.exe") do (
        if not "%%~f$PATH:i" == "%%~f$PATH:j" (
            set ANACONDA_OLD_PATH="%PATH%"
            set PATH=%ANACONDA%;%ANACONDA_SCRIPTS%;%PATH%;
            echo Added %ANACONDA% and %ANACONDA_SCRIPTS% to PATH.
        )
    )
)

if not "%ANACONDA_ENV_NAME%" == "" (
    echo Activating environment %ANACONDA_ENV_NAME%...
    set PROMPT=[%ANACONDA_ENV_NAME%] $P$G
)
```

I have very little experience with bat language but I guess there may be something to do with this line

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
```

I tried to remove that line but kept trapped in the ERRORLEVEL 1 expression with message.

```
error: unable to enable command extensions
```

Can anyone suggest what I should do to make this bat-file work properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need a batch file. Assuming that Anaconda and CMD are on your path (which they should be), you can try this as an alternative (it is what I do):

```
cmd "/c activate py3k && ipython --pylab"
```

Comment: I tried your solution but had no success until I figured out it should be `cmd "/c activate py3k && ipython --pylab"`. It works! Thanks so much!